# How to make prestep system groovy script to interrupt jenkins build and set it to SUCCESS?

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Say I have a maven2/3 project in jenkins/hudson and **BEFORE** I run some goals on a maven project configured in the correspoing config.xml file, I want to run a system groovy script (ref. system groovy plugin) during a prestep and interrupt the whole job and set it to SUCCESS if some condition is met (for example say I find something in the log file of the previous job). **I DO NOT WANT MAVEN TO START EXECUTING THE GOALS**.

I have tried

```
import hudson.model.*
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
build.executor.interrupt(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
out.print "HELLO"
```

But nothing happens, and even "HELLO" is printed in log. But then the build gets ABORTED.

```
Parsing POMs
Discovered a new module ...
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
...
...jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java -Xmx512m -cp ...
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Build was aborted
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand fully, what you want, since you described here some solution, not your exact problem. I know three plugins, which could be useful for your problem as well:

- [Fail the build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin) plugin lets you set the result of the job, and stops further processing. Any status can be set including success.
- [Conditional build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin lets you define conditions for its child build steps. If the condition is met, the child(ren) will run.
- [m2 extra build steps](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin) - lets you run build steps before or after maven build in a maven job in jenkins. Note, that recently, this plugin is the part of the core jenkins.[image]

So the basic idea is that **you could add conditional build step a pre-build step in your job, and the child step could be one fail-the build instance**. See the picture below:

Comment: That does not seem to work as a build status SUCCESS will not skip the Maven build part. It is still executed.

Comment: Hmm. Earlier it stopped the job. Maybe its a change in the fail the build plugin. Thanks for the info.